# Converting NSString to CString in Xcode Playground

Tags: xcode, nsstring, swift, swift-playground

When I attempt:

```
import Cocoa
var ns: NSString = "whatever"
var cs: CString = ns.UTF8String
println(cs)
```

in an Playground it reports this exception when executing the **var cs: CString = ns.UTF8String** statement:

```
fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
Playground execution failed: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
* thread #1: tid = 0xbf05a5, 0x000000010401b02d libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`Swift._StringCore._growBuffer (@inout Swift._StringCore)(Swift.Int, minElementWidth : Swift.Int) -> Swift.COpaquePointer + 813, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010401b02d libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`Swift._StringCore._growBuffer (@inout Swift._StringCore)(Swift.Int, minElementWidth : Swift.Int) -> Swift.COpaquePointer + 813
    frame #1: 0x000000010401643f libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`Swift._StringCore.append (@inout Swift._StringCore)(Swift._StringCore) -> () + 607
    frame #2: 0x0000000104016fa5 libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`Swift.+ @infix (Swift.String, Swift.String) -> Swift.String + 117
...truncated...
```

However the same code works as expected when compiled into an app. It looks like a Playground bug but does anyone know a workaround to convert an NSString to Cstring in the Playground?

Comment: what about ns.cString()?

Comment: ns.cString() causes the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work in the playground by making cs a CString optional.

```
import Cocoa
var ns: NSString = "whatever"
println(ns)
var cs: CString? = ns.UTF8String
println(cs)
```

and if you need to unwrap the optional

```
if let str = cs{
println(str)
}
```

Comment: Good answer! Unfortunately in my actual use case (passing the string to glShaderSource) I need an non-optional CString. When I add "var cs2: CString = cs!" to the example I'm back to hitting the exception :(

Comment: I added a snipped that should let you unwrap the optional